# How might I speed up reading from same disk in parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I read a file, and for each line in the file, I need to get more information.

This involves reading data from my non-SSD drive.

To speed things up I am trying to process in Parallel, but this means that lots of processes are trying to read different files from same drive.

So my overall speed is no faster than when I do it sequentially.

Is there anything I can do to improve performance?

```
    public void LoadModelListPAR()
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\jobs\modelList");

        modelData = new List<ModelData>();

        Parallel.ForEach(lines, (line) =>
        {
            string modelName = line.Split('_')[2].Replace("-1m", "");

            LoadTrades(modelName, @"D:\jobs\" + line);
        });
    }

      public void LoadTrades(string modelName, string modelDir)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(modelDir+"\\trades.txt");


            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                 modelData.Add(new ModelData(line));
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: Chances are disks are the slowest part of the chain.. so no, you would be restricted by disk speed

Comment: Yes, I understand it is a IO issue. However, it is a common need for me to access multiple file on the same disk. I just wondered if there were any tricks I was missing. For example, would putting a "lock" around each "ReadAllLines" improve things?

Comment: Parallel reading won't help here. Maybe it would be easer to transform your file into something with more structure, which allows more sequential reads instead of jumping around. There is also the possibility of changing scheduling/caching. Instead of read, process and read link, you would read many first-order stuff and then process the links. Not always possible and i don't really now the structure of your data. Random-access to disk-files is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should rather do is to read files asynchronously, and not in parallel. By doing so, you will use the time on your main thread which is otherwise just waiting for file operation to finish. Try something like this:

```
    public async void LoadModelListPAR()
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\jobs\modelList");

        modelData = new List<ModelData>();

        foreach(var line in lines)
        {
            string modelName = line.Split('_')[2].Replace("-1m", "");
            await LoadTrades(modelName, @"D:\jobs\" + line);
        };
    }

    public async Task LoadTrades(string modelName, string modelDir)
    {
        using (var f = new FileStream(path: modelDir + "\\trades.txt", mode: FileAccess.Read, isAsync: true))
        {
            var buf = new byte[f.Length];
            await f.ReadAsync(buf, 0, f.Length);
            var s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
            foreach (var line in s.Split('\n'))
            {
                modelData.Add(new ModelData(line));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But why would this be faster than sequential version?. I am not doing anything whilst I "await LoadTrades"

Comment: When you await, the current function execution is suspended, and current thread starts executing other operations (in your case - reading other files)

Comment: BUt is that not exactly the same as my doing this sequential?

Comment: No, the thread is not blocked, but instead it processes other files.